# Не монтируется папка: Docker-compose + Dcokerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Использую Docker-compose для создание контейнера с php-fpm.

```
php:
build: ./docker/php
container_name: php-fpm
volumes:
  - ./app:/var/www/html
  - ./docker/php/src:/var/src
  - ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php/php-fpm.conf
links:
  - mysql
restart: always
```

Когда в Dockerfile обращаюсь к папке "/var/src" выдается ошибка и оказывается, что ее нет. После проверки понял что не один из "volumes" не был монтирован.

Почему так происходит? Как это исправить?

```
RUN cp /var/src/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cp: cannot stat '/var/src/id_rsa': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, Ваш вопрос состоит в том, почему из Dockerfile "не видно" файлов из volume, которые указаны в соответствующей секции композ-файла? Ответ тогда очевиден: докерфайл ничего не знает про композ и тома, которые в нем указаны, а оперирует лишь файловой системой хоста, на котором запускается сборка.

В команде `RUN cp` первым аргументом необходимо указывать путь к существующему файлу на вашем компьютере, а вторым путь внутри создаваемого образа